# Spring Aliasing

Tags: spring, alias

В чем практический смысл Spring aliasing?

```
<bean id="testDataSource" ... />
<alias name="testDataSource" alias="dataSource"/>
```

т.е., с бином можно обращаться как по его id, так и по алиасу.
Но зачем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два бина с одним именем в `spring` создать нельзя. Однако можно перекрыть первый бин вторым при помощи `alias`. К примеру, у тебя есть две базы данных. Одна тестовая, а другая промышленная. Тебе не хочется каждый раз при тесте менять название полей в бинах, которые используют базу. Тут на помощь и приходит `alias`. Плюс при переименованиях бинов `alias` используется для обратной совместимости. Вещь редко используется, но всё же используется.